# Replacement for Jquery UI command growlUI in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

$.growlUI - is there a replacement for this.  I want to go from Jquery UI to Jquery in Bootstrap.

Basically a button in a modal is being pressed:

and here is the Jquery UI being called:

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
var auditID = this.id;
// $.blockUI({message: $('#question_alert')});
//Continue with unanswered questions
$('#yes_delete').click(function() {
  $.post("edit_audits.php?action=delete&auditID="+auditID,
  function(data) {

    if(data) alert(data);
      $.growlUI('Success','You have successfully DELETED the audit.','success',1000);
       setTimeout(function() {
         window.location.reload();
      }, 2000);
    return false;
  }); 
});
//Fix answered questions
$('#no_delete').click(function() {
  $.unblockUI();
  return false;
});
});
```

How would you call a new modal instead of using $.growlUI?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used the growl UI tool; but Bootstrap has excellent documentation on working with the built-in modal component: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Comment: I definitely need it on the JQuery side.  More than the Layout side